# How can I use grep with parameters in R?

Tags: r, regex

Obviously I dont get the way grep works in R. If I use grep on my OS X terminal, I am able to use the parameter -o which makes grep only return the matching part. In R, I can't find how to do a corresponding thing. Reading the manual I thought values was the right approach, which is better inasmuch that it returns characters not indexes, but still returns the whole string.

```
# some string  fasdjlk465öfsdj123 
# R
test <-  fasdjlk465öfsdj123 
grep("[0-9]",test,value=TRUE) # returns  "fasdjlk465öfsdj123"

# shell
grep -o '[0-9]' fasdjlk465öfsdj123
# returns 4 6 5 1 2 3
```

What's the parameter I am missing in R ?

EDIT: Joris Meys' suggestions comes really close to what I am trying to do. I get a vector as a result of readLines. And I'd like to check every element of the vector for numbers and return these numbers. I am really surprised there's no standard solution for that. I thought of using some regexp function that works on a string and returns the match like grep -o and then use lapply on that vector. grep.custom comes closest – i'll try to make that work for me.

Comment: Hmm, isn't calling some shell grep easier? How do I do that again?

Comment: @ran2 : corrected my name :-)

Comment: oups, sorry sir! I will double-check that I write at least your name correctly next time you help me ;)

Comment: @ran2 : updated my answer for vectors. Or, if you want to use the shell grep, you could look at `?sys`. Running windows here, so no chance of trying it out, but I'm sure you'll puzzle it out yourself.

Comment: ... should be ?system in case somebody else is interested

Comment: You should use `"[[:digit:]]"` instead of `"[0-9]"` if international portability is a concern (e.g. if you're using this in a package).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spacedman said it already. If you really want to simulate grep in the shell, you have to work on the characters itself, using `strsplit()` :

```
> chartest <- unlist(strsplit(test,""))
> chartest
 [1] "f" "a" "s" "d" "j" "l" "k" "4" "6" "5" "ö" "f" "s" "d" "j" "1" "2" "3"
> grep("[0-9]",chartest,value=T)
[1] "4" "6" "5" "1" "2" "3"
```

EDIT :

As Nico said, if you want to do this for complete regular expressions, you need to use the `gregexpr()` and `substr()`. I'd make a custom function like this one :

```
grep.custom <- function(x,pattern){
    strt <- gregexpr(pattern,x)[[1]]
    lngth <- attributes(strt)$match.length
    stp <- strt + lngth - 1
    apply(cbind(strt,stp),1,function(i){substr(x,i[1],i[2])})
}
```

Then :

```
> grep.custom(test,"sd")
[1] "sd" "sd"
> grep.custom(test,"[0-9]")
[1] "4" "6" "5" "1" "2" "3"
> grep.custom(test,"[a-z]s[a-z]")
[1] "asd" "fsd"
```

EDIT2 :

for vectors, use the function `Vectorize()`, eg:

```
> X <- c("sq25dfgj","sqd265jfm","qs55d26fjm" )
> v.grep.custom <- Vectorize(grep.custom)
> v.grep.custom(X,"[0-9]+")
$sq25dfgj
[1] "25"

$sqd265jfm
[1] "265"

$qs55d26fjm
[1] "55" "26"
```

and if you want to call grep from the shell, see `?system`

Comment: That does not work if you want to match more than one character. You should really use `gregexpr`, see my answer for an example.

Comment: that's pretty close, just edited my post. Thx for the help, I will try to make it work for me...

Comment: I could not upvote twice, but at least I can accepted this answer. Did not know about Vectorize. There's still a lot to learn...

Answer (score 5):

That's because 'grep' for R works on vectors - it will do the search on every element and return the element indices that match. It says 'which elements in this vector match this pattern?' For example, here we make a vector of 3 and then ask 'which elements in this vector have a single number in them?'

```
> test = c("fasdjlk465öfsdj123","nonumbers","123")
> grep("[0-9]",test)
[1] 1 3
```

Elements 1 and 3 - not 2, which is only characters.

You probably want gsub - substitute anything that doesn't match digits with nothing:

```
> gsub("[^0-9]","",test)
[1] "465123" ""       "123"
```

Comment: +1 for gsub. In my case two sequential gsubs indeed did the job. Obviously there's no single good solution, but several ways to do it...

Comment: @ran2 : hehe, you could have found that out earlier, and for the problem you subscribe in the edit, this might well be the cleanest solution. The thing is that, as the solution I gave initially, it only works for very simple cases. For more complex regular expressions you need more. See also the answer of @nico, he's right on.

Comment: @Joris Meys: finding something that works for now is one thing, but learning from the different solutions is the other.

Answer (score 4):

All this dancing around with strings is the problem the [stringr](https://github.com/hadley/stringr) package was designed to solve.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all('fasdjlk465fsdj123', '[0-9]')

[[1]]
[1] "4" "6" "5" "1" "2" "3"

# It is vectorized too
str_extract_all(rep('fasdjlk465fsdj123',3), '[0-9]')

[[1]]
[1] "4" "6" "5" "1" "2" "3"

[[2]]
[1] "4" "6" "5" "1" "2" "3"

[[3]]
[1] "4" "6" "5" "1" "2" "3"
```

The motivation behind stringr is to unify string operations in R under two principles:

- Use a sane and consistent naming scheme for functions (`str_do_something`).
- Make it so that all the string operations that take one step in other programing languages, yet fifty steps in R, take only one step in R.

Answer (score 3):

`grep` will only tell you whether the string matches or not.

For instance if you have:

```
values <- c("abcde", "12345", "abc123", "123abc")
```

Then

```
grep <- ("[0-9]", values)
[1] 2 3 4
```

This tells you that elements 2,3 and 4 of the array match the regexp. You can pass `value=TRUE` to return the strings rather then the indices.

If you want to check where the match is happening you can use `regexpr` instead

```
> regexpr("[0-9]", values)
[1] -1  1  4  1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1  1  1  1
```

which tells you where the first match is happening.

Even better, you can use `gregexpr` for multiple matches

```
> gregexpr("[0-9]", values)
[[1]]
[1] -1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1 1 1 1

[[3]]
[1] 4 5 6
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1 1

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 3
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 3):

No idea where you get the impression that

```
> test <- "fasdjlk465öfsdj123"
> grep("[0-9]",test)
[1] 1
```

returns `"fasdjlk465öfsdj123"`

If you want to return the matches, you need to break `test` into it's component parts, `grep` on those and then use the thing returned from `grep` to index `test`.

```
> test <- strsplit("fasdjlk465öfsdj123", "")[[1]]
> matched <- grep("[0-9]", test)
> test[matched]
[1] "4" "6" "5" "1" "2" "3"
```

Or just return the matched strings directly, depends what you want:

```
> grep("[0-9]", test, value = TRUE)
[1] "4" "6" "5" "1" "2" "3"
```

Comment: sry, edited my post, forgot value=TRUE. That's why I got the idea.

Comment: apparently we had the same idea at the same time. +1

Comment: @Joris: it would appear so, but you win for using `unlist()`! +1

Answer (score 2):

`strapply` in the gsubfn package can do such extraction:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> strapply(c("ab34de123", "55x65"), "\\d+", as.numeric, simplify = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   34   55
[2,]  123   65
```

Its based on the `apply` paradigm where the first argument is the object, the second is the modifier (margin for `apply`, regular expression for `strapply`) and the third argument is the function to apply on the matches.

`str_extract_all(obj, re)` in the stringr package is similar to `strapply` specialized to use `c` for the function, i.e. its the similar to `strapply(obj, re, c)` .

`strapply` supports the sets of regular expressions supported by R and also supports tcl regular expressions.

See the gsubfn home page at http://gsubfn.googlecode.com