# Alternatives to system() in R for calling sed, rsync, ssh etc.: Do functions exist, should I write my own, or am I missing the point?

Tags: bash, r

Recently, I found the `base::files` commands. Along with other commands like `getwd`, `write.lines`, `file.show`, `dir`, etc. there seem to be a number of R equivalents of bash functions.

I have also written some functions in R that streamline calls to  `ssh` and `rsync` through `system`.

for example:

```
rsync <- function(from, to){
  system(paste('rsync -outi', from, to, sep = ' '), intern=TRUE)
}
```

But before I go to much further with this, I have a few questions:

- does R already have built in commands for common shell programs, if so, where can I find them?
- if not, are there reasons to avoid writing my own functions?
- is there a better alternative to the approach outlined in the `rsync` example above?
- would a collection of such functions warrant a package?

Comment: Just wondering if you got any further with systematizing functions for interacting with shell? I would much appreciate to have a look at least at what you did for rsync and ssh to avoid reinventing the wheel. Thanks.

Comment: @r0berts the rsync and ssh wrappers are here https://github.com/PecanProject/pecan/blob/5557ffce8607738edb58422bb6dcc799c0bb4760/base/utils/R/utils.R#L103 I'd be interested to know if you take it any further!

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely look into it. Looks it is an awesome project, the bigger part of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> does R already have built in commands for common shell programs, if
>   so, where can I find them?

There are some function like `grep` that mimic shell progams.  Search for them as you would any other function – the names are often the same.

> if not, are there reasons to avoid writing my own functions?

No obvious problems.

> is there a better alternative to the approach outlined in the rsync
>   example above?

Looks good, but you need to be very careful about checking user input if things are passed to the shell.

> would a collection of such functions warrant a package?

Absolutely.  Go for it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. To clarify, with respect to grep, I am interested in doing this on files rather than R objects, as R's grep does.

Comment: speaking of grep we had discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397876/how-can-i-use-grep-with-parameters-in-r . Found the answers of this thread very helpful, though R's grep isn't quite the shell grep.

Answer (score 8):

I started to go down that route with wrapping git functions for [devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools), but eventually realised what I needed was:

```
bash <- function() system("bash")
```

with a bit of wrapping to make sure I ended up in the right directory.

Comment: could you give an example? the [`devtools::bash`](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/bash.r) function is a bit different, and when I execute the above code, it sends me to the command line, apparently equivalent to executing `q('no')`

Comment: update: except that issuing `exit` then returns to the R session, at which point `bash()` remains undefined

Comment: Sometimes you just need an quick way to jump to the command line in right location then return to R.  For me, that worked better than writing wrappers for many functions.

Comment: I still don't understand this function, since it doesn't seem to create a bash function, it only sends me to the command line, equivalent to simply issuing `system('bash')`.

Comment: I created a new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756604/what-does-bash-function-systembash-do,  so that I could understand how this works better, which I think will require more space than comments will allow, and to shift the burden from you (although your insight would be appreciated).

Answer (score 3):

There's not much out there, apparently ...

```
> library(sos)
> findFn("rsync")
found 0 matches
x has zero rows;  nothing to display.
Warning message:
In findFn("rsync") : HIT not found in HTML;  processing one page only.
> findFn("ssh")
found 27 matches;  retrieving 2 pages
2
```

The `ssh` hits are either false positives or part of parallel-processing packages (`GridR`, `nws`, `biopara`). `RCurl` has an `scp` command (based on `libcurl`, not a system call).

Comment: thanks for pointing out the [`sos`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sos/vignettes/sos.pdf) library. I've never gotten beyond `help.search` from within R.

Answer (score 0):

#### *UPDATED*

thanks to @hadley for pointing this out - the time penalty was due to using the `intern = TRUE` argument, see update below.

*Rather than deleting the answer, I am going to leave the answer up here for reference, unless it gets lots of downvotes*

---

After creating a few such commands, I have realized one disadvantage (potentially significant):

Wrapping a system call in a function increases the speed at which the function is called, almost 8-fold in this example:

Using `system`:

```
system.time(system(paste('rsync -outi', '~/dir/files* ', 'serverhost:')))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.060   0.020   0.552
```

Wrapping `system` in a new function, `rsync`:

```
rsync <-  function (from, to, pattern = "") {
    system(paste("rsync -outi", from, to, sep = " "), intern = TRUE)
  }
system.time(rsync(from = '~/dir/files*', to = 'serverhost:'))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.040   0.030   3.825
```

#### *Update*

The speed penalty resulted from the unnecessary use of `intern = TRUE`

```
rsync <-  function (from, to, pattern = "") {
    system(paste("rsync -outi", from, to, sep = " "))
  }
system.time(rsync(from = '~/dir/files*', to = 'serverhost:'))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.070   0.020   0.504
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not because in one you're using `intern = T`, or because in one you have `-r`?

Comment: @hadley thanks for pointing it out. `-r` had no effect; after removing `intern = T`, there was no difference