# What does bash in the devtools package do?

Tags: bash, r, devtools

In response to a previous question, [Alternatives to system() in R for calling sed, rsync, ssh etc.: Do functions exist, should I write my own, or am I missing the point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169202/alternatives-to-system-in-r-for-calling-sed-rsync-ssh-etc-do-functions-exis), [hadley's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169202/alternatives-to-system-in-r-for-calling-sed-rsync-ssh-etc-do-functions-exis/7746296#7746296) indicated that when faced with a similar problem, he had used a function like:

```
bash <- function() system("bash")
```

I found the original in his devtools package; [implemented in devtools/R/bash.R](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/blob/master/R/bash.r):

```
#' Open bash shell in package directory.
#'
#' @param pkg package description, can be path or package name.  See
#'   \code{\link{as.package}} for more information
#' @export
bash <- function(pkg = NULL) {
  pkg <- as.package(pkg)

  in_dir(pkg$path, system("bash"))
}
```

<strike>I don't understand the point of this. When I issue</strike>

```
bash <- function() system("bash")
```

It sends me to the bash shell, after which `exit` returns me to the R session, but there is no `bash` function. It seems that I can get the same effect by either issuing either of the following command pairs (first command in R, second in bash)

```
system('bash')
exit
```

or

```
q('yes')
R
```

*the striked part were due to a copy/paste error on my part*

I also can not find any further uses of the `bash` function in the devtools package

Can someone please help me understand how the `bash` function could be used; can it be used in contexts (e.g. within scripts or functions) other than interactive R mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Earlier versions of `devtools` included some functionality to push/pull code to git/github.  This has now been deprecated.

Instead, the convenience function `bash` simply opens a bash editor in the package directory.  This means you can use command line tools to interact with git/github.

The purpose of `bash` is simply to save a few keystrokes to open the command line in the package directory.  It serves no other function.

Answer (score 4):

Then either you didn't type

```
bash <- function() system("bash")
```

exactly like this, on a single line. This is what I get:

```
> bash <- function() system("bash")
> bash()
[gavin@prometheus cocorresp_check]$ exit
> ls()
 [1] "a"       "b"       "bash"    "cars.lo" "dat"     "Dbig"    "Djackal"
 [8] "foo"     "i"       "jack.t"  "jackal"  "mat"     "mat2"    "meanDif"
[15] "mod"     "N"       "perm"    "x"       "Xa"      "Xab"     "Xb"     
[22] "xct"     "y"
> match.fun("bash")
function() system("bash")
```

Note that `bash()` is the third object listed. So the first line defines the function, I use it on the second line to drop to a bash shell, which I promptly exit returning me to the R prompt.

If the function isn't defined in your working environment then whatever you did to define it didn't work. It would appear from your description that R just executed `system("bash")`.

Comment: thanks for catching my error. I updated my question a bit; but I still wonder - is this useful outside of using R interactively?

Comment: @David I don't think it has any use outside of interactive R usage. All it does is open a bash prompt in the current directory and pass control to it - R is in effective in limbo until control is returned to it.